# Exclude organizations from getting Activity Schedule Reminder

Tags: scheduled-reminders

We have a Schedule Reminder sent when contacts sign up for a new membership. Specifically, it is sent when a Membership Sign-up activity was added to a contact (as opposed to using the membership start date). Since a membership assigned to both individuals and organizations, is there any way to exclude only the organizations from receiving the Schedule Reminder?

Comment: You could try building a smart group based on your criteria and then limit the scheduled reminder to that group - I have no real live example of it working in practice but may work (smart groups may have related issues with scheduled reminders but if reminder has a delay it may work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a smart group with all Individuals in it. In Schedule reminder you can use 'Limit to' field to set as group.

Comment: Thanks for this! The UI does make it seem that it's gonna send the Schedule reminder to everyone in the smart group (instead of just activity recipients that are in the smart group).